# Android L, exception using joda.time Library

Tags: android, time, jodatime, android-5.0-lollipop

An app used to work in all devices including (nexus 5 and nexus 7). Running the same app on Android L preview, the app crash.

I have been debugging and the exception was founded calling DateTime Constructor.

```
public static String[] getAge(Context context, Date date) {
        DateTime time = new DateTime(date);
        DateTime nowTime = new DateTime(new Date());

}
```

Log:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Incorrect signature
at org.apache.harmony.security.utils.JarUtils.verifySignature(JarUtils.java:223)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.verifyCertificate(JarVerifier.java:294)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.readCertificates(JarVerifier.java:268)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:380)
    at libcore.net.url.JarURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(JarURLConnectionImpl.java:222)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:444)
    at org.joda.time.tz.ZoneInfoProvider.openResource(ZoneInfoProvider.java:202)
    at org.joda.time.tz.ZoneInfoProvider.<init>(ZoneInfoProvider.java:123)
    at org.joda.time.tz.ZoneInfoProvider.<init>(ZoneInfoProvider.java:82)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.getDefaultProvider(DateTimeZone.java:490)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.setProvider0(DateTimeZone.java:444)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.<clinit>(DateTimeZone.java:116)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils.<clinit>(DateTimeUtils.java:48)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils.getChronology(DateTimeUtils.java:282)
    at org.joda.time.convert.AbstractConverter.getChronology(AbstractConverter.java:82)
    at org.joda.time.base.BaseDateTime.<init>(BaseDateTime.java:170)
    at org.joda.time.DateTime.<init>(DateTime.java:241)
```

Any idea about?

Comment: It looks like Joda Time is trying to read some files out of its own JAR. If one of your hardware devices is running Android 4.4, you might enable the ART runtime on it in Developer Options and see if you get the same problem. If you do, then the problem most likely stems from the ART runtime.

Comment: Seems like jodaTime could be trying to call a now-private API? According to https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/3de7083091497358d003bb889eba909f85b69fad/luni/src/main/java/org/apache/harmony/security/utils/JarUtils.java verifySignature is checking for Application signature, maybe to check it against the system signature. Just a wild shot though.

Comment: Enabling the ART runtime on Android 4.4.4 is working and no exception appeared… Still on Android-L

Comment: I couldn`t resolve this issue, so I guess that this library is not supported by Android-L. Instead of this solution using Date class there is no exception.