# Lollipop throwing Incorrect Signature for SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, crash, google-maps-android-api-2, android-5.0-lollipop, supportmapfragment

I have an android app that shows a map via a SupportMapFragment. The app was running fine for the past several months until just recently I upgraded my phone from 4.4.4 to 5.0 (via the official OTA update). Now the app crashes and I get the following stack trace:

```
11-18 12:51:49.699  12594-12594/com.foo.bar E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.foo.bar, PID: 12594
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.foo.bar/com.foo.bar.CallActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #89: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #89: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
            at com.foo.bar.CallActivity.onCreate(CallActivity.java:89)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Incorrect signature
            at org.apache.harmony.security.utils.JarUtils.verifySignature(JarUtils.java:223)
            at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.verifyCertificate(JarVerifier.java:294)
            at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.readCertificates(JarVerifier.java:268)
            at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:380)
            at libcore.net.url.JarURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(JarURLConnectionImpl.java:222)
            at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:444)
            at java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(Class.java:1334)
            at com.google.l.a.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.l.a.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.b.e.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.b.e.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.b.e.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.dm.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.dw.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.v.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.u.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
            at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:920)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1206)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2159)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateVie
```

Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".CallActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here's my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.foo.bar"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 126
        versionName "1.0.126"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

and here is the relevant bits of the activity:

```
public class CallActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_call); // this is line 89 (the line referenced in the stack trace)
        ...
```

The same app still works fine on another phone with an older version of android. And if I remove the fragment from the layout, it runs without crashing on my phone with 5.0 (of course without the map), so I'm fairly certain it's the map fragment that's causing the issue.

Has anyone else seen anything like this? Any ideas of what to try?

Comment: It seems like my issue may be related to this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556447/android-l-exception-using-joda-time-library]

Comment: This could be related as well: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26528445/android-l-lollipop-java-lang-securityexception-incorrect-signature)

Comment: This could also be related to this, since my project does include the spongycastle jars (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68562). Seems odd though since the encrypt/decrypt bits seem to work just fine in lollipop. I only get the crash when it tries to inflate the view. And as soon as I take out the fragment, the activity loads with no issues. Really stumped on this one.

Answer (score 5):

Try to change

```
static {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
}
```

with

```
static {
    Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
}
```

See also

https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle-old/issues/10

Comment: Thanks! Works for us. We had a "SecurityException: Incorrect signature"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was related to spongycastle. I had the following in my application class:

```
static {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
}
```

As soon as I commented out that block, it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Remove BouncyCastle/SpongyCastle provider when Google Map view is created.
Then add it again when Google Map view is destroyed.

Create fragment inherited from SupportMapFragment.
Override onCreateView and onDestroyView.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (Build.VERSION.RELEASE.equals("5.0"))
    {
        Security.removeProvider("SC");
    }
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    if (Build.VERSION.RELEASE.equals("5.0"))
    {
        Security.addProvider(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Use this inherited fragment instead of SuuportMapFragment in layout xml.